# Arithmetic and Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Given that 4th, 9th and 12th term of an arithmetic series equal to the 5th, 8th and 15th terms of a geometric series, show that the common ratio r of the geometric series satisfies $5r^{10}-8r^3+3=0$

So Let the first term and common difference of the AP be a and d, first term of GP be b. then $a+3d=br^4,a+8d=br^7,a+11d=br^{14}$ but I don't know how that leads to the desired result,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3$ times first equation $+$ $5$ times third equation $-$ $8$ times second equation.

$$3(a+3d-br^4) + 5(a+11d-br^{14}) - 8 (a+8d-br^7) = 0 \\ \implies 5br^{14} - 8br^7 + 3br^4 = 0 \\ \implies 5r^{10} - 8r^{3} + 3 = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $b$ is a first term of a geometric series.

Thus,
$$\frac{br^7-br^4}{5}=\frac{br^{14}-br^7}{3},$$
which gives what you wish.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you! :)

Comment: Please see comment on @robjohn's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $r\ne1$ and $r\ne0$. We can deal with these cases separately. In this case, $r^8-r^5\ne0$, so
$$
\frac{r^{15}-r^8}{r^8-r^5}=\frac{g_{15}-g_8}{g_8-g_5}=\frac{a_{12}-a_9}{a_9-a_4}=\frac35\tag{1}
$$
means that
$$
5r^{15}-8r^8+3r^5=0\tag{2}
$$
Since we have assumed that $r\ne0$, we can divide by $r^5$ to get
$$
5r^{10}-8r^3+3=0\tag{3}
$$
$r=1$ provides a solution, and satisfies $(3)$.

$r=0$ provides a solution, but does not satisfy $(3)$. If we want to encompass all solutions, we could use
$$
5r^{11}-8r^4+3r=0\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thank Youfor the explanation! I have an unanswered question too at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356355/geometric-series-and-sum-to-infinity

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  -  does this imply $r\neq 1$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: I have improved the discussion of $r=0$.

Comment: Noted. But @MichaelRozenberg pointed out in a comment elsewhere (but he is quiet here) that such a solution does not work $r=1$ as it involves division by $0$.

Comment: @hypergeometric: unless Michael Rozenberg has commented on this answer, I don't think paging him here will get to him.

Comment: @hypergeometric I think this solution is bad. Try $r=1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: when $r=1$, the sequences are constant. If you're worried about division by $0$, just cross multiply rather than dividing. The formulas will be a bit less concise and less clear, but they will give the same results.

Comment: @robjohn♦ I don't need nothing with your solution because it's your solution, which is bad I think. See please my solution. We have no there problems with $r=1$ and $d=0$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: how do you get the $3$ and $5$ if $d=0$?

Comment: @robjohn♦ By your solution I can not get it. See my solution and we'll can get it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: by casing $r=0$ and $r=1$ separately, things get handled properly. I've looked at your answer and I don't see where you get the $3$ and the $5$ when $d=0$.

Comment: @robjohn♦ For $r=1$ and for $d=0$ I can change $3$ and $5$ at all number different zero.  I used $d=\frac{a_m-a_n}{m-n}$, where $m\neq n$